# Unnecessary serialVersionUID in Retrofit 2 Request Body

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2, okhttp

I am doing request from Android Client with Retrofit2. My request type is PUT and request Model is:

```
public class BusinessStatus {

  public enum STATUS
  {
    AVAILABLE, UNAVAILABLE
  }

  public STATUS status ;

  public BusinessStatus(STATUS status) {
    this.status = status;
  }

}
```

My retrofit api interface service is:

```
public interface BusinessStatusApi {

  @PUT("abul/{driverId}/abulass")
  Observable<Response<Void>> updateBusinessStatus(@Path("driverId") String driverId, @Body BusinessStatus businessStatus);

}
```

I am making the PUT request from Presenter like this:

```
 public void updateAbulAssStatus(final String driverId, STATUS status) {
    BusinessStatus businessStatus = new BusinessStatus(status);
    Observable<Response<Void>> call = mBusinessStatusApi
        .updateBusinessStatus(driverId, businessStatus);

    Subscription subscription = call
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(
            response -> {
              if (response.isSuccessful()) {

              } else {
                Toast.makeText(mContext.getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
            },
            e -> {
              if (e instanceof HttpException) {
                ResponseBody responseBody = ((HttpException) e).response().errorBody();
                Timber.d("ErrorMessage", responseBody);
              }
            },
            () -> {
              Timber.d("Status", "Completed");
            }
        );

  }
```

But an **unusual unnecessary serialVersionUID is added to Request Body** and getting 400 from Backend API.

Here is my okhttp log:

```
PUT http://localgost:8080/v1/abul/10011/abulass http/1.1
09-15 14:55:01.394 12402-12578 D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
09-15 14:55:01.397 12402-12578/ D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 62
09-15 14:55:01.398 12402-12578/ D/OkHttp: {"status":"AVAILABLE","serialVersionUID":-1766960164825680704}
```

why there is unnecessary serialVersionUID being added there despite it is not included in request Model?

Answer (score 1):

Serial version (**serialVersionUID**) is an unique identifier and used to determine if different versions of a type is compatible.

So for example, you are sending an enum and internally Retrofit has to serialize the value to send it over the network.

If the response is of same type then you would expect that Retrofit will deserialize the response and give you the same enum type.

In serialization process, Java performs a calculation and generate a value named **serialVersionUID**. The signature is like,

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = -1766960164825680704L;
```

Retrofit, by setting a custom value for **serialVersionUID**, is taking the responsibility to ensure compatibility.